# wget --post-data and retrive page with result table

Tags: html, wget

Main page link: http://kalimatimarket.com.np/daily-price-infomation

```
<h1>Daily Price Information</h1><hr>
<form name="price" id="price" method="post" action=""  >
    <table>
    <tr><td> Date : </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker" class="required"></td>
    <td> Price Type : </td>
    <td><select id="pricetype" name="pricetype" class="required">
        <option value="W">Wholesale</option><option value="R">Retail</option></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="View" name="view" onclick=dlypriceview() ></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
<div id="pricelist">
    </div>
```

how to post data in this form?

my try

```
wget --post-data 'date=09/01/2014&price=post&view=1' http://kalimatimarket.com.np/daily-price-infomation -O market.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to post to the wrong URL.

**Try these:**

`wget --post-data 'cdate=09/01/2014&pricetype=W' http://kalimatimarket.com.np/priceinfo/dlypricebulletin -O wholesale_market.html`

or

`wget --post-data 'cdate=09/01/2014&pricetype=R' http://kalimatimarket.com.np/priceinfo/dlypricebulletin -O retail_market.html`